# Convert this JSON to a tree and find the path to parent

Tags: json, path, tree, parent

```
data= {
"saturn": [
        "planet",
        "american_car",
        "car"
    ],
    "american_car": [
        "car",
        "gas_driven_automobile"
    ],
    "planet": [
        "large_object",
        "celestial_body"
    ],
    "large_object": [],
    "gas_driven_automobile": [
        "gas_powered_road_vehicle",
        "car"
    ],
    "car": [
        "vehicle",
        "motor_vehicle"
    ],
"vehicle": [],
"motor_vehicle": [],
"gas_powered_road_vehicle": [],
"celestial_body": []
};
```

I need to write an algorithm where if I give the input "saturn" I need to get all the possible paths from saturn to different parents. for example,

```
saturn ->planet ->large_object  
saturn ->american_car->car->vehicle
saturn ->american_car->car->motor_vehicle
saturn ->american_car->gas_driven_automobile->gas_powered_road_vehicle
saturn ->american_car->gas_driven_automobile->car->vehicle
```

and all the other possible paths.

I was thinking of somehow converting this to a tree and then using a library to calculate the path from the child to the parent.

Working on writing an algorithm, can't figure out how to start off on converting this to a tree.

Comment: Which language do you use? Can you use any libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), you can simply define a recursive function:

```
def parents($key):
  if has($key)
  then if .[$key] == []  then [] else .[$key][] as $k | [$k] + parents($k) end
  else []
  end;
```

To use it to produce the "->"-style output, invoke jq with the -r command-line option, and call the above function like so:

```
["saturn"] + parents("saturn")
| join(" -> ")
```

## More economically

```
def lineages($key):
  [$key] + (lineages(.[$key][]) // []);


lineages("saturn") | join(" -> ")
```